# How do I transfer data from a chip over Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to develop an android application that will use Bluetooth capabilities to transfer data from a chip to an Android phone. I have not changed the code from the tutorial on the developer's website at all.

I am getting the following error:

```
_context cannot be resolved as a variable
```

Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LocalBluetoothDevice localBT = LocalBluetoothDevice.initLocalDevice(_context);
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {    
        // Device does not support Bluetooth        
    }
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {    
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);    
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
LocalBluetoothDevice localBT = LocalBluetoothDevice.initLocalDevice(this);
```

or

```
Context context = this;
LocalBluetoothDevice localBT = LocalBluetoothDevice.initLocalDevice(context);
```

Comment: When i tried this it came up with the error that initLocalDevice is undefined for the type LocalBluetoothDevice

Comment: which is the main activity of your project? you need to do Context context = YourMainActivity.this, and then use it